# How to fix the firebaseApp.getOrInitService error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Currently getting a `firebaseApp.getOrInitService` error while trying to get a secondary app's Firestore

using firestore-admin v10.3.0 if that changes something

Initializing runs correctly with no errors

```
 initializeApp({
      credential: cert(saAccount),
    }, "secondary");
```

But once I attempt to get the firestore that's when it errors

```
getFirestore("secondary")
```

error:

```
TypeError: firebaseApp.getOrInitService is not a function
```

Comment: did you find a solution? currently facing this same error